# Saving URL parameter in session for mobile to opt-out responsive design

Tags: php, session, parameters

I have a responsive Wordpress site: www.2eenheid.de. My client wants an option on a mobile to view the site in fullsize, an opt-out responsive option. Now with the help of a fellow programmer here I got this:

```
<?php ini_set('display_errors', true);

session_start(); 
if(isset($_REQUEST['resp'])) {
     $_SESSION['resp'] = (bool)($_REQUEST['resp']);
}

// Check if enabled
$enabled = isset($_SESSION['resp']) && $_SESSION['resp'];


?><!DOCTYPE html>

<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />

<?php if($enabled): ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<?php endif; ?>

<title>LALALA</title>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?> id="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['resp']) && $_SESSION['resp']) { echo "resp"; } ?>">
```

It sort of works. Whenever I call the link www.2eenheid.de/?resp=1 my site turns to responsive on mobile, but it won't save this setting when i click on other pages and I need it to be. Also some pages are responsive and some aren't. I feel like theres something i did wrong at `$_SESSION['resp'] = (bool)($_REQUEST['resp']);`. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['resp'])){
 $enabled = true;
}else{
 $enabled = false;
}
```

use this instead of

```
$enabled = isset($_SESSION['resp']) && $_SESSION['resp'];
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. If you can check on mobile (www.2eenheid.de). It looks like it randomly shows responsiveness..

Comment: have you used var dump on $_SESSION['resp'] to see what is outputted?